# Ant task to delete everything in a directory but one file

Tags: wordpress, ant

I'm working on an Ant script to help with a Wordpress deployment (I know...).  The idea here is to:

- delete the entire `vendor` directory.
- delete the entire `public_html/wp` directory.
- delete everything from `public_html/content/plugins` except for the one PHP file: `public_html/content/plugins/w3tc-wp-loader.php`.

This is what I've tried (along many variations):

```
<delete failonerror="false" quiet="false" includeEmptyDirs="true">
    <fileset dir="vendor" />
    <fileset dir="public_html/wp" />
    <fileset dir="public_html/content/plugins">
        <exclude name="w3tc-wp-loader.php" />
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

This kinda works:

- it deletes the contents of the `vendor` directory except for a few `.gitignore` files that exist in subdirs, so those files and their parent dirs still exist (i.e. `vendor/composer/installers/.gitignore`).
- `public_html/wp` is deleted, as expected.
- `public_html/content/plugins` is left containing a bunch of subdirectories, each of which is empty (except one has a `.gitignore` file).  The excluded file noted in the Ant script is left, as expected.

Any idea why a) the empty dirs aren't removed and b) `.gitignore` files seem to stay as well (as well as their parent dirs)?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this way:

```
<delete failonerror="false" quiet="false" includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${root}" defaultexcludes="false">
       <include name="vendor/**" />
       <include name="public_html/wp/**" />
       <include name="public_html/content/plugins/**" />
       <exclude name="public_html/content/plugins/w3tc-wp-loader.php" />
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

where `${root}` is the parent directory for `vendor` and `public_html`.

`defaultexcludes="false"` will make sure your `.gitignore`s will be deleted as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your .gitignore files are excluded by default http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes. To delete them add `defaultexcludes="false"` to `fileset`